Executing an Oracle function which returns Cursor in JDBC
I have here an Oracle DataWarehouse and have to execute the following function:
function getUserSelection(
  p_userID in number,
  p_userDate in date,
  p_userCompany in string,
  p_mode in number default null)
return v_c

According to our DB admin v_c should be a cursor.
It does nor work from Java. What I tried:
String sqlQuery = "{ ? = call getUserSelection(?,?,?,?) }";
CallableStatement callStmt = con.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
callStmt.registerOutParameter("v_c", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callStmt.setInt("p_userID", 123);
callStmt.setDate("p_userData", new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMilis()));
callStmt.setUserCompany("p_userCompany", "Kiwi");
callStmt.set("p_mode", 0);
callStmt.execute();

This leads to the error
not supported sql92 token at position 10

Then tried the following:
String sqlQuery = """
   begin ? := getUserSelection(?,?,?,?); end;
""";
    CallableStatement callStmt = con.prepareCall(sqlQuery);
    callStmt.registerOutParameter("v_c", OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    callStmt.setInt("p_userID", 123);
    callStmt.setDate("p_userData", new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMilis()));
    callStmt.setUserCompany("p_userCompany", "Kiwi");
    callStmt.set("p_mode", 0);
    callStmt.execute();

and am getting
java.sql.Exception ORA-06550 Row 1 Column 20 PLS-00103 Found symbol '>' while expecting :=.(@%;"

Oracle Function itself works fine, I can execute it from SQL Developer without issues.
Any ideas?

Does that function execute in SQL Plus?

The call escape is for calling stored procedures. I guess you need to call it using a prepared statement (not callable statement) using select getUserSelection(?,?,?,?) from dual.

What is the actual sql code?

You are also mixing SQL with positional parameters (?) and Java with named ones ("v_c", ...)

According to the [PL/SQL] function declaration in your question, v_c is a [database] type - which is not really the same as a cursor. Can you [edit] your question and post the SQL statement that defines the v_c type? I am referring to the CREATE TYPE statement.

From the code in your question: callStmt.registerOutParameter("v_c", OracleTypes.CURSOR); You are mixing JDK classes with Oracle JDBC classes. I think you need to use java.sql.Types with CallableStatement or else use OracleCallableStatement with OracleTypes.

I would suspect that something like DECLARE v_c  SYS_REFCURSOR; when used in the function with the Java code, might have a more favourable result

Typo. p_userData not p_userDate in callStmt.setDate("p_userData", new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMilis()));

So, I was able to execute it properly, when setting values with setObject() and number only:
callStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callStmt.setObject(2, 123);
callStmt.setObject(3, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMilis()));
callStmt.setObject(4, "Kiwi");
callStmt.setObject(5, 0);
callStmt.execute();

This way it works, I can execute the procedure and can get the response I expect. However, not being able to use proper procedure names looks bad to me...
Now to your questions:

Yes, the code works, as I wrote above in orignal posting, wonderfully in SQL Developer
This OracleCallableStatement seems also to be a good idea, I didn't know that there is a special CallableStatement for Oracle. Will try it, too.
I cannot post you the code of the SQL itself due to company's data disclosure policy, sorry.


Prefer callStmt.setObject(3, java.time.Instant.now());
